# Encoding x64 VCOMISS instruction

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, machine-code

I'm looking at the VCOMISS instruction on page 576 of the Intel x64 manual:

VEX.LIG.0F 2F.WIG /r

Two problems... 1. 0x2F isn't a valid mandatory prefix and 2. there's no opcode

Anyone know what the story is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2F is the opcode, there is no mandatory prefix. A mandatory prefix would be shown before the 0F. The WIG is in the wrong place (great, an other error in the manual.. copy and paste error perhaps?)

It should read:

> VEX.LIG.0F.WIG 2F /r

Comment: Thanks Harold!!  You're a life-saver as always!